# After stopping service of certain DataNode, how to remove the service of this DataNode from cluster of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I now want to stop DataNode service and remove it from the current Apache IoTDB cluster. I want to know if I already stopped DataNode, do I still need to execute the remove command (`sbin/remove-datanode.sh`) to completely remove this DataNode service from the cluster? Are there any action aside from remove command that I still need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are trying to shrink the cluster datanode in Apache IoTDB, then you still need to execute the `sbin/remove-datanode.sh` command to complete the removing process. However, shrinking cluster may be failed, so it is recommended to back up the data under the datanode first, so you can still import the data you need if the process failed.